# How to hide the display value in the column of Dojo dgrid?

Tags: dojo, tree, grid, dgrid

We are currently using a tree grid of dojo dgrid. The expanding arrows of tree grid are placed as first column. This first column is mapped with a attribute in the store.

Currently the value of that attribute is getting displayed along with the expending arrow. But our requirement is to hide the value and display only the arrows.

Can anyone suggest a way to configure this requirement in tree dgrid column?

Answer (score 0):

Tree's logic for rendering expand icons attempts to piggyback off of any existing `renderCell` function for the column in question.  By default, dgrid renders the value pertaining to the field each column represents, but you could easily override your expand icon column to have an empty `renderCell` function (i.e. `renderCell: function () {}`), and then Tree would simply add the expand icon to an otherwise empty cell.